# Laptop overheating within minutes of start up

Tags: shutdown, overheating, dell-studio

I have a Dell Windows 7 Home Prem with an I7-720QM. More information on the computer can be found here http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/servicetag/51CVCN1/configuration

The Problem I am having is the computer will over heat unnaturally fast. From the time it takes from boot to when i can run my diagnostic tools which takes about two minutes the cpu temp is 86c after a few more minutes the cpu temp will reach 100 and the computer will black screen shut down. In total the the laptop can only be run for 3-5 minutes before completely shutting off. During this time there is nothing extensive running. After the laptop shuts down you have to wait for it to cool down or it will shut off even faster sometimes 7-15 seconds well still in the boot screen.

Does anyone know what could be the problem maybe a sensor or is the computer fried?

Comment: Is the fan even running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was a corrupt OS, which ended up causing a hug memory leak. The processor was working way to hard to deal with not having any memory.

I found this by booting into windows safe mode, where the problem still occurred, so I booted into windows recovery mode, where the problem stopped.

A format of the OS fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Classic sign of either a major dust build up or (more likely) the processor heatsink compound/paste has dried up and has caused the heatsink to break away from the processor.

You need to take it apart or take it to a professional repairer.

don't keep turning it on as the temperature can significantly reduce the processor life span.

It shouldn't be too difficult to repair if the paste has dried up and the laptop will function perfectly from then on (in almost all cases).